# Как добавить кастомные поля в GridView?

Tags: yii2

Делаю страницу с стандартным **GridView** в **Yii2** с **ActiveDataProvider** в котором

`'query' => Product::select('title as customField', .......)`

Модель **Product(id, title, price)**, в **gridColumns** я хочу указать:

```
[
   'label' => 'Кастомное поле',
   'attribute' => 'customField', <--- которое я достаю в select
],
```

В итоге, получается что показывается чистая таблица у которого **customField** пустое, но записи точно есть.

Я понял что у меня в query приходит набор объектов **Product**, **gridview** смотрит в **Product** и не находит **customField**, из-за этого пусто.
Если добавить в модель public string $customField; то таблица заработает правильно.

Вопрос, как можно это исправить без добавления **public string $customField** в модель **Product**?